# django rest framework order listview by serializer specific field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

So I currently have a Drink serializer built using django rest framework. It has a field `count_need` that i obtain using a `SerializerMethodField`, which is not part of the Drink model. It also has a `timestamp` field that is part of the model. How can I order the ListAPI view by either `timestamp` or `count_need` based on parameters from a get request like `/api/drink/?ordering=timestamp`. Currently, i have ordering fields specified in the ListAPI view `ordering_fields = ('count_need', 'timestamp', )` but it doesnt seem to be ordering the apiview on either query. I can order it by `timestamp` through the `get_queryset` method but this doesnt work for `count_need` because it is not part of the model.

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding the `get_queryset` method on your View and add an annotated field on your queryset for count_need.  I think this would be preferable as it may be faster in SQL for large lists, and works with the built-in OrderingFilter of rest framework.

Example:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class MyView(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.queryset
        qs = qs.annotate(count_need=Count('need'))
        return qs
```

Recommended Reading:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses

The other option is to implement some custom ordering in Python instead of using the Django ORM.  You could do this by overriding the `list` method on your ListAPI view.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        serializer_data = serializer.data
        sorted_serializer_data = sorted(serializer_data, key=lambda x: x['count_need'])
        return self.get_paginated_response(sorted_serializer_data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    serializer_data = serializer.data
    sorted_serializer_data = sorted(serializer_data, key=lambda x: x['count_need'])
    return Response(sorted_serializer_data)
```

Comment: Wow the second part of your answer is fantastic, I'll implement it in the morning and comment if it works! Thanks. It looks like it should as far as I can see